# Getting full documents using ElasticSearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I've got an index like:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Alex",
        "LastName": "Ich",
        "Department": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Charlie",
        "LastName": "Sheen",
        "Department": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "Peter",
        "LastName": "Petrelli",
        "Department": 5
    },
    {
        "Name": "Alan",
        "LastName": "Harper",
        "Department": 6
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ann",
        "LastName": "Bottle",
        "Department": 3
    },
]
```

And I want to get the results with distinct `Department`, I don't care about order, just 1 result per `Department`. I tried with *aggregations* but I could only manage to get the different `Deppartments` with the *doc_count* associated. They query I tried is something like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "deppartments": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Department"
      }
    }
  },"size": 0
}
```

It returns:

```
"buckets": [
    {
        "key": 2,
        "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
        "key": 3,
        "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
        "key": 5,
        "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
        "key": 6,
        "doc_count": 1
    },
]
```

When I want something like:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Alex",
        "LastName": "Ich",
        "Department": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Charlie",
        "LastName": "Sheen",
        "Department": 3
    },
    {
        "Name": "Peter",
        "LastName": "Petrelli",
        "Department": 5
    },
    {
        "Name": "Alan",
        "LastName": "Harper",
        "Department": 6
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) for this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "departments": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Department",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "search_results": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10   <--- you can change the size to 1 if you want
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Does this help?